# Таймер обратного отсчета plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите таймер обратного отсчета. Что-бы каждый час перезагружался 
С самым обычным стилем 58 Минут 33 Секунды

Comment: [В базе знаний уже есть ответы на такой вопрос!..](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0+)

Answer (score 0):

что-то подобное ))

```js
let min = 1;
let sec = 10;

let nameObj = {
  0: {
    sec: 'Секунд',
    min: 'Минут'
  },
  1: {
    sec: 'Секунда',
    min: 'Минута'
  },
  2: {
    sec: 'Секунды',
    min: 'Минуты'
  },
  3: {
    sec: 'Секунды',
    min: 'Минуты'
  },
  4: {
    sec: 'Секунды',
    min: 'Минуты'
  },
  5: {
    sec: 'Секунд',
    min: 'Минут'
  },
  6: {
    sec: 'Секунд',
    min: 'Минут'
  },
  7: {
    sec: 'Секунд',
    min: 'Минут'
  },
  8: {
    sec: 'Секунд',
    min: 'Минут'
  },
  9: {
    sec: 'Секунд',
    min: 'Минут'
  },
};
setMin();
setSec();

function setSec() {
  if (sec === -1) {
    sec = 59
    setMin();
  }
  $('#sec').text(sec);
  $('#sec-name').text(getName(sec, 'sec'));
  sec--;
  setTimeout(setSec, 1000);
}

function setMin() {
  min--;
  $('#min').text(min);
  $('#min-name').text(getName(min, 'min'));
  if (min === 0) {
    min = 60;
  }
}

function getName(val, name) {
  let valStr = '' + val;
  let lastVal = valStr[valStr.length - 1];
  return nameObj[lastVal][name];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="min"></span>&nbsp;<span id="min-name">Минут</span>&nbsp;<span id="sec"></span>&nbsp;<span id="sec-name"> Секунды</span>
```